# Symfony: Send email automatically every 7 days during one month

Tags: php, symfony, email, hyperlink, confirmation-email

I need your help on my current project with Symfony...
When you click in a button, the function must send an email to other user with a link confirmation. This email must be send every seven days during one month. How can I create a confirmation link? How can I do the part of sending emails?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, take the [tour], and read [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sending the emails part you can create a cron-job that runs every 7 days to call a command which sends the emails.

You can check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html) how to send emails and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) how to create a command.

You can check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/2369/403904) to see how to create a cron-job.

Comment: Hi Alex! First of all, thank you for your reply. I have a little question, How can I activate the cron-job when I click in a button?

Comment: When clicking the button the first time, you can call the sending of email function from within your controller.

The cron-job can call the same function to send the emails based on your logic.